# Приветствие в зависимости от времени суток

Tags: python, python-3.x

В процессе написания голосового ассистента захотел сделать приветствия в зависимости от времени суток

```
opts = { "hey" : ('привет', 'здравствуйте', 'доброе утро', 'добрый день', 'добрый вечер', 'доброй ночи')}

now = datetime.datetime.now()

if now.hour >= 4 and now.hour <= 12 :
        greet = opts["hey"][2]
if now.hour >= 12 and now.hour <= 16 :
        greet = opts["hey"][3]
if now.hour >= 16 and now.hour <= 0 :
        greet = opts["hey"][4]
if now.hour >= 0 and now.hour <= 4 :
        greet = opts["hey"][5]

def talk(words) :
    print(words)


talk(greet.title() + "." + " Чем я могу помочь?")
```

При этом приветствие всегда "Доброе утро". Как исправить проблему?

Comment: and....................

Comment: Запустил код и получил "добрый день".

Comment: А "добрый вечер" этот код никогда не выведет.

Answer (score 2):

Условия прописаны не правильно

```
import datetime
opts = { "hey" : ('привет', 'здравствуйте', 'доброе утро', 'добрый день', 'добрый вечер', 'доброй ночи')}

now = datetime.datetime.now()
now += timedelta(hours = 1) # можешь проверить тут
#print(now.hour)
if now.hour > 4 and now.hour <= 12 :
    greet = opts["hey"][2]
if now.hour > 12 and now.hour <= 16 :
    greet = opts["hey"][3]
if now.hour > 16 and now.hour <= 24 :
    greet = opts["hey"][4]
if now.hour >= 0 and now.hour <= 4 :
    greet = opts["hey"][5]

#print(greet)
#print(now)
```